# mysql Databases how can I fix this?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Hi Im trying to set up a database to store emails using ruby, sinatra, ActiveRecord, and mysql. Any suggestions on what im doing wrong? Im trying to output it to a seperate page that only i can see and then post it using a url on hostgator.

```
  require 'sinatra'
  require 'activerecord'
  # require 'sinatra-activerecord'


   get '/' do

   erb :index
   end

   def save_email (email)
   file.print(email)
   end



  get '/email' do
  params[:email]


  # # redirect '/'
  end


  post '/email' do

  params[:email]
  @email = params[:email]
  erb :email, :locals => {:email => params[:email]}

  end

  # Change the following to reflect your database settings
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql', # or 'postgresql' 
  host:     'localhost',
  database: 'Stored_Emails',

 )
 class Stored_Emails < Sinatra::Application
 end

class Stored_Emails < ActiveRecord::Base
end

ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table :email do |t|
t.string :emails
end

create_table :emails, force: true do |t|
t.string :email
t.belongs_to :email, index: true
  end




get '/email' do
params[:email].all
end
```

Comment: What's the problem here? This is quite the jumble of code.

Comment: Yes sorry I've looked at too many resources and think I've combined the wrong syntax's. I am having trouble getting the database to start up because I am running into errors. The main error being that I am missing an argument @tadman

Comment: Errors help immeasurably when explaining your problem, so you need to communicate what those are and which lines in this they refer to.

Comment: ok ernel_require.rb:55:in `require' is what it says in terminal, its hard for me to decipher it though.

Comment: everything up until the ActiveRecord::Base. is correct

Comment: If this is your actual code you might want to clean it up a bunch first, organize it, and build it incrementally.

Comment: thats what I don't know how to do. However, still trying and getting better

Answer (score 0):

Typically you break out your code into multiple files (we use folders named config, helpers, libraries, views, routes, models, migrations) and require them at the top of your app.  However, if you want to put it in the same file and just use that and a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock that'll work too.  Here's how it might look:

```
# Require your gems
require 'sinatra'
require 'activerecord'

# Libraries

# Models
class Stored_Emails < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Configuration
# Change the following to reflect your database settings
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql', # or 'postgresql' 
  host:     'localhost',
  database: 'Stored_Emails'
 )

ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table :email do |t|
  t.string :emails
end

# Migrations
create_table :emails, force: true do |t|
  t.string :email
end


# Helpers
def save_email (email)
  file.print(email)
end

# Routes
get '/' do
  # Load whatever you want to show in your index page into class variables
  erb :index
end

get '/email' do
  Stored_Emails.all.to_json
end

post '/email' do
  @email = Stored_Emails.find_by(params[:email])
  erb :email
end
```

Now you're going to have to do a good bit of work to get this running.  Here's what I suggest you read:

1) Sinatra documentation - http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

- routes
- running your sinatra app
- views with ERB

2) Bundler documentation for gems - http://bundler.io/

3) ActiveRecord documentation - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

- Connecting to a database Creating your database with a migration -
  this is a one time deal Querying the database

Good Luck!

Comment: thank you so much. This is great advice. When I was trying to do this, I was jumping ahead of my class to learn it. Now I have a better grasp and know exactly what to do with your guidance. Thanks again!